# Android webview allow access to camera with current Android Studio

Tags: android, webview, camera

I have been trying to make a simple input button work on my webview that accesses the camera and files.  The solutions I've read vary from a couple lines of code with no explanation of where they go to blind github project links (Os-Fileup and others) that I download and open in Android Studio and they often have dozens of files with nothing that really helps me as I don't know what I'm looking for.

I've tried various solutions of including this package or that, requesting permissions, etc but none have solved the issue for me as I probably implemented them incorrectly or they were for much older versions of Android or Android Studio. I am using the very latest version of Android Studio and am targeting only Oreo 8.1 (minSdkVersion 27 and targetSdkVersion 28).

For the initial setup of my webview app, I followed a simple tutorial I found somewhere and everything is working - other than the camera.

I finally read somewhere than granting permission to the app (eg: access to the camera, to the app on the device) does not carry through to the webview - so that's where I'm stuck.  There are only two files - AndroidManifest and MainActivity.java   ... so those two files look like what you see below - what in the world do I change in those files to just make the button work in the app that works just fine on the same device in a browser?

The button from the webview.loadURL page:

```
<input id='uploadImage' type='file' accept='image/*' name='image' />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="redacted.name.here">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_ns_n"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_ns_n"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webview.loadUrl("https://redacted.url.here");
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webview,true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

After additional searching I found some newer code that I was able to edit to make it work for me where I got the dialog box asking if I wanted to use the Camera or pick a file.

Edit the package name and the URL to match your project.  I left all the section that were commented out in the code I copied from in the code below but I will be removing most of them in my own project.

I hope this helps someone else.

I made no changes to my HTML or the AndroidManifest.xml file.

MainActivity.java

```
package {put your package name here};

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webview;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessages;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);



        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webview.loadUrl("https://{put your URL here");
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webview,true);


        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + webview.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // For api level bellow 24
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                if (url.startsWith("http")) {
                    // Return false means, web view will handle the link
                    return false;
                }

                return false;
            }


            // From api level 24
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                /*Toast.makeText(mcontext, "New Method",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                // Get the tel: url
                String url = request.getUrl().toString();

                if (url.startsWith("http")) {
                    // Return false means, web view will handle the link
                    return false;
                }

                return false;
            }

            // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+

           /* public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                openImageChooser();
            }*/

            // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices

            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                mUploadMessages = filePathCallback;
                openImageChooser();
                return true;
            }

            // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0

           /* public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }

            //openFileChooser for other Android versions

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }*/
        });

    }

    private void openImageChooser() {
        try {

            File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FolderName");

            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");

            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            if (null == this.mUploadMessage && null == this.mUploadMessages) {
                return;
            }

           /* Uri result;
            if (requestCode != RESULT_OK){
                result = null;
            }else {
                result = intent == null ? this.mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();
            }
            this.mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            this.mUploadMessage = null;*/
            if (null != mUploadMessage) {
                handleUploadMessage(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

            } else if (mUploadMessages != null) {
                handleUploadMessages(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleUploadMessage(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        Uri result = null;
        try {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                result = null;
            } else {
                // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null

                result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void handleUploadMessages(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        Uri[] results = null;
        try {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                results = null;
            } else {
                if (intent != null) {
                    String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                    ClipData clipData = intent.getClipData();
                    if (clipData != null) {
                        results = new Uri[clipData.getItemCount()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                            results[i] = item.getUri();
                        }
                    }
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                } else {
                    results = new Uri[]{mCapturedImageURI};
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mUploadMessages.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUploadMessages = null;
    }

}
```